# Why did Vim create a constantly growing .swp file?

Tags: vim, diskspace, swapfile

Someone had opened `vi` via ssh, and pasted output into a buffer, and then later closed / crashed that terminal.  The system was later discovered to be out of disk.

Self-answering.

Prior unaddressed reports, usually with no or mocking responses:

https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/RRJOfwOXtlA?pli=1

> I use vim on Linux all the time and found a problem with creating just huge swp files that can take up all the hard disk space.
> If you open vim and copy a large text that can cause the linux console to hang and then you force close the console, after a couple of days the swp file size can reach hundreds of gigabytes. I have already encountered this problem twice and each time I had to look for where these swp files were created in which directory.
> I am using vim version 8.0.1453.

https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/8oy57j/issue_about_huge_swp_file_cause_disk_full/

> today ,one of my linux server disk full and i find two vim swap file cause this problem

https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/86ny08/cause_of_300gb_swap_file_oo/

> I had a text file (python code, maybe 100 lines) open for a few days and afterwards delete it (and, at some point, closed the vim terminal holding it).
> Lo and behold, a few days later I run out of space and track down the issue to ~/.vim/file.py.swap eating up a whopping 298GBs of disk

Answer (score 1):

My immediate suspicion on "pasted into buffer" was that it was not done in insert mode, which triggered some repeated commands to be executed.

I was able to reproduce this very quickly by opening a new file, and typing commands similar to

- `100000iA<esc>` (create a long line)
- `yy10000000p` (paste it a lot of times)
  I did some other poking around with saving partial versions, so there might be more to the reproduction (which I don't plan to reproduce, see below).

The following behaviors were observed

1. `.swp` file grew rather quickly (~1GB/sec)
2. `vim` process that was unkillable, even by `sudo kill -9` (osx)

   1. There was a plugin subprocess that was also unkillable
   2. Closing the terminal holding `vi` did nothing
   3. Tried with `Full Disk Access` enabled, didn't help
   4. Didn't disable `System Integrity Protection`
   5. Normal reboot resolved
3. Removing the `.swp` file

   1. This only appeared to stop it
   2. The `.swp` file returned a few minutes later (still growing)

Version info

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Sep 01 2022 15:00:53)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-350
```